# Is it possible to get audio input in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, pyaudio

My question is if it is possible to get audio as an input?
like: user_input = input(audio)

this is what my code looks like atm, after looking at this you will understand better what I seek for.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
adLoop = True

detector = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    detector.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)


    while adLoop:
        print("Please speak")
        audio = detector.listen(source)
        final_text = detector.recognize_google(audio)
        adLoop = False
        print("Converted speech: ", "\n", final_text)

        print("Would you like to convert more words to text?: Y/N")
        audio_two = detector.listen(source)
        fianl_text_two = detector.recognize_google(audio_two)
        if fianl_text_two == "yes":
            adLoop = True
            print("Final text: ", "\n", final_text + fianl_text_two)
        elif fianl_text_two == "no":
            adLoop = False
            print("Done")
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to get audio input.

Comment: But how can I the audio input from console?

Comment: I want it to work like, after first loop ends, i want to ask the user if they want to continue or not(for e.x: user_input = input("Would you like to continue:?  "), but how do I get the audio answer from them?

Comment: to get audio from user you already have `audio = detector.listen(source)` but if you want to get it as text then you have to use `detector.recognize_google(audio)`